# Always pull using HTTPS, push using SSH, using insteadOf?

Tags: git, github

I have a number of repositories using different Github URL formats. I would like all repositories to always fetch from Github over HTTPS, and to push over SSH. This makes my life easier, with ssh keys / agent forwarding /...

This would make sense to me, but it doesn't rewrite a couple of cases:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
    pushInsteadOf = "https://github.com/"
[url "https://github.com/"]
    insteadOf = "git@github.com:"
```

e.g., for a test repository with three remotes:

- hh: http fetch, http push
- hs: http fetch, ssh push
- sh: ssh fetch, http push

That is:

```
% git remote -v
hh  https://github.com/foo/bar (fetch)
hh  https://github.com/foo/bar (push)

hs  https://github.com/foo/bar (fetch)
hs  git@github.com:foo/bar (push)

sh  git@github.com:foo/bar (fetch)
sh  https://github.com/foo/bar (push)
```

...this config generates:

```
% cat .gitconfig 
[url "git@github.com:"]
    pushInsteadOf = "https://github.com/"
[url "https://github.com/"]
    insteadOf = "git@github.com:"

% HOME=. git remote -v   
hh  https://github.com/foo/bar (fetch)
hh  git@github.com:foo/bar (push)

hs  https://github.com/foo/bar (fetch)
hs  https://github.com/foo/bar (push)  # wrong

sh  https://github.com/foo/bar (fetch)
sh  https://github.com/foo/bar (push)  # wrong
```

What git config snippet will generate the "http fetch, ssh push" remotes I want in all cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This would make sense to me, but it doesn't rewrite a couple of cases

If you have an explicitly configured push URL for a repository then you cannot override it with `pushInsteadOf`. Refer to the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-urlltbasegtpushInsteadOf):

> **`url.<base>.pushInsteadOf`**
>
> Any URL that starts with this value will not be pushed to; instead, it
>   will be rewritten to start with `<base>`, and the resulting URL will
>   be pushed to. In cases where some site serves a large number of
>   repositories, and serves them with multiple access methods, some of
>   which do not allow push, this feature allows people to specify a
>   pull-only URL and have Git automatically use an appropriate URL to
>   push, even for a never-before-seen repository on the site. When more
>   than one `pushInsteadOf` strings match a given URL, the longest match
>   is used. **If a remote has an explicit pushurl, Git will ignore this
>   setting for that remote.**

Note that the [`url.<base>.insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) setting is applied unconditionally, which explains why your SSH push URL (for the `hs` remote) was replaced with an HTTPS URL:

> **`url.<base>.insteadOf`**
>
> Any URL that starts with this value will be rewritten to start,
>   instead, with `<base>`. In cases where some site serves a large number
>   of repositories, and serves them with multiple access methods, and
>   some users need to use different access methods, this feature allows
>   people to specify any of the equivalent URLs and have Git
>   automatically rewrite the URL to the best alternative for the
>   particular user, even for a never-before-seen repository on the site.
>   When more than one `insteadOf` strings match a given URL, the longest
>   match is used.

So, to achieve your goal you must

1. remove the `url.<base>.insteadOf` setting from your git config file(s).
2. individually set fetch/pull and/or push URLs for all your remotes that deviate from your desired scheme.

Answer (score 7):

Try using:

```
[url "https://github.com/"]
  insteadOf = "git@github.com:"
[url "git@github.com:"]
  pushInsteadOf = "https://github.com/"
  pushInsteadOf = "git@github.com:"
```

This will force all pulls to use HTTPS, and pushes to use SSH. The second `pushInsteadOf` is a little nonsensical, as it rewrites a `git@github.com:` to the same `git@github.com:`. But, this prevents the `insteadOf` from rewritting the `git@github.com:` to `https://github.com/` for pushes.

With this:

```sh
# initial: git@github.com:git/git.git
git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/git/git.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:git/git.git (push)

# initial: https://github.com/git/git.git
git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/git/git.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:git/git.git (push)
```

The important part is that `pushInsteadOf` rewrites push URLs **first**, and if theres a match it prevents an `insteadOf` from rewritting. By making `git@github.com:` -> `git@github.com:`, we've locked in the push URL. The regular `pushInsteadOf` will still rewrite an initial HTTPS into SSH for pushes, and the `insteadOf` will still rewrite a SSH into HTTPS for pulls.